# Find values in sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite

I have an sqlite database that has one table and 4 columns in that one table. It is a a large sqlite database file around 60GB.

I have a separate smaller csv file that only has one column and about 10 rows.

How can I check to see if the values in the smaller csv file is also in the sqlite database and return the row if it is found?

Here is some sample code but I am stuck on how to compare values in the csv file to the values in column 2 of the sqlite database.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect( 'database.db')
c = conn.cursor()
conn.commit()
c.execute(""" SELECT name, number,zip 
from table """)
query = c.fetchall()

with open('smaller.csv','r') as smallerfile:
    with open('output','w') as output:
    reader = csv.reader(smallerfile)
    writer = csv.writer(output)
```

Comment: Answering this will be extremely difficult without knowing what the data looks like. Can you include any of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're approaching this the wrong way round. You need to iterate through the CSV file, and for each row do a query on the database to find any matching rows.

```
with open('smaller.csv','r') as smallerfile, open('output', 'w') as output:
    reader = csv.reader(smallerfile)
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    for row in reader:
        c.execute("SELECT name, number,zip from table WHERE name=?", row[0])
        for result in c.fetchall():
            writer.writerow(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, I am trying it now. It's a really slow lookup. The database is quite large.

Comment: @JohnMarshall Then you need an [index](https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html) on the `name`.

Comment: @CL. I do have an index on name and that was not helpful.